# JFoenix in Java 11

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jfoenix

this is my pom.xml file for using javafx 11 and JFoenix 9 in my project.
But when I compile and run javafx with maven it gets me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXGenericPickerSkin (in module com.jfoenix) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx.binding to module com.jfoenix
```

I have added this commands to compilation options:

```
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix
```

Still nothing changes. Can someone help me to solve it? I'm using Intellij IDEA and Java 11.0.3.

My module-info.java file:

```
module com {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires com.jfoenix;

opens com.Client.Controller to javafx.fxml;
exports com;
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.App</mainClass>
                <options>
                    <option>--add-opens</option>
                    <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix</option>
                    <option>--add-opens</option>
                    <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix</option>
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you compilation options to your pom.xml file like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <options>
        <option>--add-opens</option>
        <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-opens</option>
        <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-exports</option>
        <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-exports</option>
        <option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-exports</option>
        <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-exports</option>
        <option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix</option>
        <option>--add-exports</option>
        <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix</option>
        </options>
        <mainClass>com.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```